# GORM inheritance custom Identifier

Tags: inheritance, grails, grails-orm

I'm currently create an Auditing of some Domain Classes and created an `AuditingListener` that calls an ServiceMethod to save the old data.

In this Service Method i get the Audit Class of the Domain Class bysome Naming conventions.

That all works fine but now i'm heading to an problem with the Audit Class.
The Audit Class extends from the base Domain Class like this:

```
class Foo {
   String baaar
}    
class FooAudit extends Foo {
    Long auditId
    Date auditDate = new Date()
}
```

My problem is that i want to keep in `FooAudit` the id of `Foo` and have an own id property.
In the Service Method that will create the Audit Entry I'm getting an Map of all properties of the origin Domain Class Object.
I would like to set with this map the properties of `FooAudit` but the map contains also the `id` property of `Fooo`.

If I'm set the properties by the map like

```
def auditEntry = new FooAudit()
auditEntry.properties = map
```

this would set the identify of `FooAudit` the same like `Foo` but i want to have an own identify of `FooAudit`

How can I set the property `auditId` as identifier of `FooAudit`?

Answer (score 1):

As an example, I have, for the case of copying properties with special cases, a class with static methods like the followings (maybe it's usefull... and you can handle the id the way you like...)

```
static def fillObjectProperties(def map, def obj, def excludeArray, def typeConvMap) {
    map.each {
        if (obj.hasProperty(it.key) && !excludeArray.contains(it.key)) {
            try {
                if (it.value == null || it.value.size() == 0) {
                    obj.setProperty(it.key, null)
                }
                else if (typeConvMap.containsKey(it.key)) {
                    if (typeConvMap[it.key] == 'int') {
                        obj.setProperty(it.key, it.value as int)
                    } else if (typeConvMap[it.key] == 'BigDecimal') {
                        obj.setProperty(it.key, it.value as BigDecimal)
                    } else if (typeConvMap[it.key] == 'Date') {
                        Date date = new Date()
                        date.clearTime()
                        date.set(date: map[it.key + '_day'] as int, month: (map[it.key + '_month'] as int) -1, year: map[it.key + '_year'] as int)
                        obj.setProperty(it.key, date)
                    }
                } else {
                    obj.setProperty(it.key, it.value)
                }
            } catch(Exception ex) {}
        }
    }
}

static def copyObjectProperties(def source, def target) {
    target.metaClass.properties.each{
        if (it.name != 'metaClass') {
           it.setProperty(target, source.metaClass.getProperty(source, it.name))
        }
    }
    return source
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create one base class which would hold all necessary properties?

```
class FooBase{
    String baaar
}

class Foo extends FooBase{
}

class FooAudit extends FooBase {
    Long auditId
    Date auditDate = new Date()
}
```

Comment: That could work if I don't need the `id` of `Foo` in `FooAudit`, but in this case I need it . So this would not work for me...

Comment: And how are you doing audit? You could do insert to FooAudit in `beforeUpdate` event of Foo.